# IDLE interactive shell doesn't scroll properly when pressing enter

Tags: python, python-idle

I just started learning Python using a tutorial.

Whenever the tutor presses enter in the IDLE interactive shell the window scrolls down so his latest code stays in the middle of the screen.

Now for me it's different:
Whenever I press enter the window just extends to the bottom which results in the code being at the bottom of the screen and thus I have to keep dragging/scrolling the window up.

This is highly annoying and I hope someone can help me out.
Thank you!

Checked the options but couldn't find anything that relates to the problem.

Comment: What OS and x.y.x Python version are you using?  In any case, IDLE's Shell works the same way as terminal/console programs.  Initial entries and responses start at the top of the windows.  Subsequent entries and responses work down the window until hitting the bottom.  Further entries are at the bottom, forcing the oldest previous entries to scroll off the top.  One can scroll up to see lines that have disappeared.

Comment: It sounds like the 'tutor' was doing something non-standard.  Was the 'tutor' a person or a program?  Did you see it live or recorded? What OS, python version, and software framework did it use?